# If a space is complete with respect to some metric is it complete with respect to any other metric?

Tags: metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

In proving if a metric space is complete the defined metric on it is considered. For example $\mathbb{R^n}$ is complete with respect to the 'standard' Euclidean metric. I was wondering if being complete is intrinsic to a space such that it is *enough* to show that it is complete with respect *one* metric so it will be complete with respect any other metric?

Otherwise, is there any counterexample?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$ it is not complete in respect to the standard Euclidean metric but is complete in respect of the metric defined by the riemmanian metric ${{\langle, \rangle}\over{\|x\|}} $.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{R}$ is complete with respect to the usual metric but is not complete with respect to the metric $$d(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{\sqrt{1+x^2}\sqrt{1+y^2}}$$. (Take the sequence  $a_n=n$. It's Cauchy but doesn't have a limit)